# Will the new expression ever return a pointer to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, types, new-operator

In this [excellent answer by AndreyT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810295/183120), he explains that in C, when a function needs an array whose dimension is known at compile-time, it's a major technique-level error to declare

```
void process_array(int *ptr, size_t plen);
```

instead of

```
void process_array(int (*arr_ptr)[10]);
```

Furthermore, he opines that many programmers are oblivious to the second option and know only about the first. One of the reasons, he writes, for this behaviour is when an array needs to be dynamically allocated and passed to the second version, programmers don't know how to do it; they're so accustomed to `int *p = malloc(sizeof(*p) * 10)` which returns an `int *`. In C, the way to do it is, as he shows

```
int (*arr_ptr) [10] = malloc(sizeof(*arr_ptr));
```

---

This got me thinking on how one would do the same in C++. I know we've `std::array`, `std::vector`, etc. but I'm interested in understanding `new`'s usage. So I tried doing this:

```
typedef int Array10[10];
Array10 *p = new Array10;    // error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘int (*)[10]’
```

When I change `p`'s type to `int*` the compiler (GCC 4.8.1) is happy. I looked up C++11 standard (draft n3337, `§5.3.4/5`) to understand this further, it says:

> When the allocated object is an array (that is, the *noptr-new-declarator* syntax is used or the *new-type-id* or *type-id* denotes an array type), the *new-expression* yields a pointer to the initial element (if any) of the array. [*Note:* both **new int** and **new int[10]** have type **int*** and the type of **new int[i][10]** is **int (*)[10]** — *end note*]

I understand that `new int [10]` is in action; what I get back should be freed using `delete [] p` and not `delete p`. However what I need seems to be the latter, where the allocation is not an array of integers but an array itself, as a single/whole object.

Is there a way to do it? Or my trying to do this in itself shows a misunderstanding of the C++ type system? Or it is right but is simply not allowed by the standard?

---

<sup>**Aside:** When a function takes an array whose size is fixed, as in option 2, IMHO the best thing to do for the calling function is to declare an automatic array instead of resorting to dynamically allocating one and worrying about clean-up.</sup>

Comment: a better highlight in that standards quote is **denotes an array type**,  which explains your Array10 test

Comment: @Cubbi: Haha... perhaps. I've faithfully formatted it as-is in the document i.e. whatever is in boldface and italics are from the standard and the emphasis isn't mine.

Comment: The answer is in the text you quoted:

    `int(*p)[10] = new int[1][10];`

You could also do this:

    `int(*p)[10] = reinterpret_cast<int(*)[10]>(::operator new(sizeof(int[10])));`

Comment: @jrok: but that seems to be a hack to me; with multidimensional array and `reinterpret_cast`. Dunno, may be it's not a hack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [int (\*p) \[4\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382951/int-p-4)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate of the question, but [Charles Bailey's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3383747/1505939) fully answers this question

Comment: Thanks for the link to Bailey's answer. It explains the rationale behind why the returned pointer can never have the right dimension embedded in it.

Comment: well.. I agree that the new[] can allocate an array of a size dictated by the runtime state, but then, now, 9 years later than Charles's answer, we **do have** compilers that trace `constexpr`s very well, and there's an obvious compile time vs run time difference between `new int[6]` and `new int[x]` where x is `int` and `new int[x]` where x is constexpr.. IMHO, the first one could easily return `(int(*)[6])` type and the last: `(int(*)[x])`... I only hope this gets included in the standard at some point of time

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact it is suggested in the standard text you quoted:

```
int (*arr_ptr)[10] = new int[1][10];
```

The pointer returned by the new-expression has type `int (*)[10]`, i.e. pointer to array of 10 ints. You need `delete[]` to delete it.

Comment: +1 Not what I asked, but close. It doesn't return just a pointer to an array, it returns a pointer to the first element of an array of _pointer to an array_, hence one can't `delete` it, but only `delete []` it.

Comment: It does return a pointer to an array, it doesn't return a pointer to "the first element of an array of pointer to an array".  The latter would be `new (int (*[5])[5])`. It does require `[]` to delete , as you say.

Comment: Had it been `int [2][10]` wouldn't it still return `int (*) [10]` which is nothing but the pointer to the first element of an array of (array of 10 `int`s). Just that the count is 1 in the previous case, but still an array of one element, thus one has to use `delete []`.

Comment: Yes that's right. The first element of "array of array of 10 ints" is an array of 10 ints. Also, any object can be considered as an array of 1 element of whatever type it is.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly what you want then you can use std::array. For example

```
{
    typedef std::array<int, 10> Array10;

    Array10 *p = new Array10;
    delete p;
}
```

Comment: No. I've clearly stated in the question that there're workarounds using the standard C++ library, but I want to do it using the language grammar only, not its library facilities. It's more on the lines of understanding the C++ type system.

Comment: @legends2k the thing to understand here is not the C++ type system (well - that is useful but not the key issue); the key issue is with the syntax for `new`. Doing `new ` *some-array-type* gets you a pointer to *the first element of* an array with that type, whereas `new ` *non-array-type* gets you a pointer to the whole object of non-array-type.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it's the syntax of `new` that should be inspected and not type system in general here. Agree to the next point as well.